# Solving an integral using a keyhole based integral (text given)

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration

This is an interesting complex analysis problem; **The figure on the bottom left is what is being referred to,Fig7-10.**

[image: Keyhole Problem from Schaum's Outline:]

First, lets take a look at the complex line integral.

**What is the geometry of the complex line integral?**

If we look here [enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Line_integral_of_scalar_field.gif)

The real line integral is a path, but then you make a 3d figure, and it is the area under the 3d shape.

What about for complex integral?

And

How is in the solution:

$$\int_{BDEFG} = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{(Re^{i\theta})^{p-1}iRe^{i\theta} d\theta}{1 + Re^{i\theta}}$$

How is the integral around the $BDEFG$, the same as the area from 0 to $2\pi$

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I don't think there is a simple geometric interpretation of a contour integral. The picture you've linked talks about functions $f: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$. The so called scalar fields. While you are working with $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$.

If you would like to dive into geometric approaches to complex analysis I would advise "Visual Complex Analysis" by Needham. (If you got the time to dig through it)

2) Take the parameterization $BDEFG\leftrightarrow z(\theta) = Re^{i\theta}$ with $\theta$ from $0 \to 2\pi$ and $z'(\theta) = iRe^{i\theta}$.

$$\int\limits_{BDEFG} \frac{z^{p-1}}{1+z} \operatorname dz = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(Re^{i\theta})^{p-1}}{1+Re^{i\theta}}\cdot iRe^{i\theta} \operatorname d \theta$$

Comment: Hello, But how do you determine the limits of integration?

Also, I understand the domain is $x$ and $y$, The contour along the x-axis refers to a function of $x$. I understand the range, $z = x + iy$ Considering $y=0$ we get $z = x$ So is that how the x-axis function is $f(x)$?

Comment: The circular arc $BDEFG$ is complete circle with radius $R$ punctured at $(R,0)$. Which means the angle $\theta \in {]0, 2\pi[}$ and those are the integration bounds. I don't understand your second question regarding the domain $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Thank you for responding. $Re^{i\theta}$ is simply the polar representation of the point $z$ isnt it? But is **integration from** $0 \to 2\pi$ the same as **integration *along* the contour**? Thanks

Comment: That's true. The definition of a contourintegral is as follows. Given a contour $\Gamma$ with smooth parameterization $z(t)$ where $t\in [a,b]$ and $z'(t)\not = 0$ then $$\int_\Gamma f(z)\operatorname d z = \int_a^b f(z(t)) \cdot z'(t) \operatorname d t$$

Comment: How do we know that $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$? It can be extended to $\theta \in [0, 4\pi]$ cant it?

Comment: Because the contour goes around once. If you would use the parameterization $z(\theta) = Re^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$ then $\theta$ would run from $0\to 4\pi$ which would have the same result. You can't circle around twice because at $R+0\cdot i$ the contour breaks into 2 straight lines $AB$ and $HG$.

Comment: that makes sense. Is there any other way to parametrize?

Comment: You could parameterize the circular curve as $z(\theta) = R\cos\theta + iR\sin \theta$ which is in essence (because of Euler's identity) the same as $Re^{i\theta}$. I think the latter one would be the most efficiënt parameterization.

Comment: Thank you very much. It also says little later take the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ why do we take this to go to $0$ but we take $R \to \infty$?

Comment: Because you want to solve: $$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^{p-1}}{1+x}\operatorname dx$$ meaning you would like the bounds of the integral $\int_\epsilon^R$ to be transformed in the first one. Try to understand why certain contours aid in calculating real integrals. (Especially the bounds)

Comment: I see. It becomes $\int_{0}^{\infty}$ But it doesnt make sense to integrate from $\int_{\epsilon}^{R}$ ? How can you can integrate from a "length" to another "length"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19689/discussion-between-dietervdf-and-amad27).